# Which approaches are there for implementing parent -> child communication?

Tags: reactjs

I'm fluent in React, but have a question about how other people implement `parent -> child` communication. In my particular case I have a generic `<Modal />` which is specialised with others, such as `<SearchModal />`. However, in `<SearchModal />` I want to close the modal which has its functionality implemented in `<Modal />`.

Thus in **SearchModal.js**:

```html
<Modal ref={storeReference}>
    <!-- ... -->
</Modal>
```

How would you invoke the `close` function defined in `<Modal />` from `<SearchModal />`?

It's worth noting that whilst I'm using Redux, the `<Modal />` holds its own state for whether it's open or closed, as I don't believe such information belongs in my Redux store. Invoking `setState` from an external component also seems wrong.

Comment: pass a prop and listen for it in `componentWillReceiveProps`, at least with your setup. Generally I think you have it backwards though. your modal shouldn't have state.. it should just show or hide based on props, that doesn't mean you need to put that state in redux (though there's no reason it shoudn't be in redux)

Comment: I suppose if you needed to have multiple modal components up at the same time then your setup is better, but I think that's a rarer case.

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` does make a lot of sense, and something I've used because you can then update the `state`. However, in many cases I use the `<Modal />` directly if its content is simple, which leads me to believe that the `<Modal />` managing its own state makes perfect sense. As far as I see, the downside to the `componentWillReceiveProps` approach is that `<SearchModal />` must also maintain a `visible`/`open` state to pass to `<Modal />` which seems like a duplication of state. Thoughts?

Comment: This is sort of why I think you have it backwards. Why does SearchModal have Modal on the inside? It makes more sense to me to pass the Search content into your modal component. `<Modal component={<Search />} />` or dynamically `<Modal component={acitveModalComponent} />` if activeModalComponent is null, don't show the modal. if it's not null show the modal